# Stepper in a singlechildscrollview throw layout error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Main Screen Code Block:

```
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
endDrawer: const AppDrawer(),
body: SingleChildScrollView(child: FieldDetailsStepper(uid: '')));
```

Stepper Code Block :

```
class FieldDetailsStepper extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
const FieldDetailsStepper({Key? key, required this.uid}) : super(key: 
key);
final String uid;

@override
ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => 
_FieldDetailsStepperState();
}

class _FieldDetailsStepperState extends 
ConsumerState<FieldDetailsStepper> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
FieldDetailsBidStepperViewModel fieldDetailsStepperVm = 
ref.read(fieldDetailsStepperViewModel);

return Directionality(
textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
child: EnhanceStepper(
type: StepperType.horizontal,
physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
currentStep: ref.watch(fieldDetailsStepperViewModel).currentStep,
onStepContinue: fieldDetailsStepperVm.stepContinue,
onStepCancel: fieldDetailsStepperVm.stepCancel,
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controlsDetails) 
=>
_buildStepperButtons(controlsDetails),
steps: [_buildFieldDimensionsStep(), _buildWorkStepsStep(), 
_buildPriceSectionsStep()]),
);
}

Widget _buildStepperButtons(ControlsDetails controlsDetails) {
return Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
children: [
_buildStepperButton(Colors.grey[300]!, () => 
controlsDetails.onStepCancel!(), 'ביטול'),
const SizedBox(width: 30),
_buildStepperButton(Colors.purple[300]!, () => 
controlsDetails.onStepContinue!(), 'שלב הבא'),
],
),
);
}
```

Error: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

The stepper code block could be any stepper with some random widgets and its still throw the error i mentioned above .

Comment: Are you using any package for `FieldDetailsStepper` and `EnhanceStepper` ? Else can you include these widgets.

Comment: The package `EnhanceStepper ` is pretty young. Also, do you want to scroll the Stepper itself or its contents / steps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Dabbel I want the scroll of the page (Singlechildscrollview) to grow when stepper contents height is growing (When user add dynamicly data ) .

Comment: @YeasinSheikh hey i added the FieldDetailsStepper Widget the EnhanceStepper is a package but i tested it with material stepper and the result was the same .